# Lightbox JS Error on Magento in IE9 - Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, magento, internet-explorer-9, lightbox

Debug from IE

Line: 2
Character: 580
Code: 0
Error Message: Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined
URL: http://100repupgrade.clubnetdev.com/fresh//media/js/skin/reprebate/js/lightbox_cp.js

URL where problem can be seen: http://100repupgrade.clubnetdev.com/fresh/featured/the-hundreds-mike-jacket-grey.html

At the above URL, if you click on the 'Size' drop down box, the debug error pops up as copied above. This is coming from a Magento extension that is apparently compatible with this version of Magento (1.6.2.0). The section it appears to be referring to in the js file is:-

```
while(this.imageArray[imageNum][0]!=imageLink.href){imageNum++;}}
```

This is only an issue in IE9 (and possible other IE versions), there is no problem in Firefox, Chrome etc.

When the problem occurs, clicking on the drop down box should just display the product size options but instead it is loading a dark overlay associated to the lightbox.

Would anybody be able to identify at all what the issue could be and how to fix at all please? This has had me stumped for about two hours now.

Any help greatly appreciated - thanks.

EDIT: More Info.

An exact replica of this site and code works fine at http://www.reprebate.com/featured/the-hundreds-mike-jacket-grey.html by the way. This issue has only become apparent since upgrading Magento from 1.4 to 1.6 but the lightbox extension developer definitely reckons his extension works on 1.6... Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see, you are seeing an issue with Lightbox or Prototype, not the extension.

My recommendation would be to ensure you have Lightbox 2.05 and the latest version of prototype - if you want to keep using the prototype version.

If you are happy to move to a jQuery version, [Lightbox 2.5](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#download) is your best bet

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated prototype.js from 1.6.x to latest stable release 1.7 and this fixed the issue. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. You would think the latest release of Magento would be equipped with the latest versions of these libraries but obviously not.

Comment: Glad it worked! I completely agree with you, upgrading jQuery/Prototype is always one of the first things I do when downloading Magento

Answer (score 3):

Same problem here. Solved by upgrading from prototype.js 1.6 to 1.7.

Comment: As Ryan suggested above, upgrading the prototype.js file from 1.6 - 1.7 solved the issue for us too. IE was displaying a black screen originally whenever a user clicked on a signup form but this has now been solved.